# Buffer/Cache use 100% Memory

Tags: linux, caching, memory-management

I have a Linux box installed centos 6.6 with 7 GB RAM running Apache on top of it, every night Buffer and cache consume 6 GB memory out of 7 GB but when i check it through top command no process use that much RAM but only Buffer/Cache does...please help.

Answer (score 1):

Linux tries to make good use of all the free memory, so it is used to cache the system I/O  (files transfered to/from memory) in order to reduce further disk access (in your case, serving faster the static content.)

It dynamically reduces the buffer/cache when the processes require more space. For example, changing the Apache configuration to use more modules or spawn more workers.